# GCP Workflows sleep limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I read the [Workflows docs](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#sleeping) and I'm wondering if there's any limit on the sleeping step.

Is it possible to use it for long sleep (ex. 24 hours)  and then continue to the next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a workflow to sleep as long as it's within the execution duration limit.

The Workflows syntax supports 64 bit integer and `sys.sleep` accepts input in seconds however there's a [hard limit](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas#request_limits) on the duration on how long a workflow can be executed which is 1 year.

In theory, if your workflow sleeps greater than 1 year from start time to end time of the execution, then it will time out.